# Laravel if statement in form generator to select checkbox

Tags: php, laravel

I want to automatically select a checkbox when the field in the database is filled in.
I am trying to use `@if` statement in the Form generator but it is not checking the checkbox.

Here is the code I am using:

```
{!! Form::checkbox('offer_made', 'offer_made', @if(empty($phase_2->offer_made)) 1 @endif) !!}
```

Im sending this over to the view in my Controller:

```
public function show(Order $order)
{
    $order = Order::where('id', $order->id)->first();
    $current_phase = $order->current_phase;
    if($current_phase == 1) {
        $phase_2 = Order_Phase_2::where('order_id', $order->id)->first();
        return view('orders.phase-2', compact('order', 'phase_2'));
    }
}
```

When I echo `$phase_2->offer_made` in the view it shows `1` so the value is coming through but the `if statement` is not working inside the Form builder.

Anyone knows how to fix this?
Thanks already!

Answer (score 0):

You might be checking for the value incorrectly:

```
@if(empty($phase_2->offer_made)) 1 @endif)
```

This outputs a 1 if the value is empty. You should be checking for `!empty()` if I understand the field correctly.

So you might have success with this:

```
@if(!empty($phase_2->offer_made)) 1 @else 0 @endif)
```

Is the value 1/0 itself? Use `$phase_2->offer_made` directly as the third parameter.

Comment: I'm getting following error: `syntax error, unexpected token "<", expecting ")" (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/orders/phase-2.blade.php)`

Comment: No, I meant just put `!` in front of the empty() call. If you have a syntax error now the code was incorrect before.

Answer (score 0):

use ternary operator as you cannot use blade syntax in php code. Try something like this:

```
{!! Form::checkbox('offer_made', 'offer_made',(!empty($phase_2->offer_made)) ? 'checked' : '') !!}
```